# ConsoleZ (Console2 Port) Change Background Color per Pane

Tags: windows, colors, console2

I have downloaded [ConsoleZ](https://github.com/cbucher/console) for paned terminal windows. I am wondering if anyone here knows how to set background colors per pane? For example, I might monitor apache2 `errors.log` in one pane and `access.log` in another. Would be nice to delineate the two panes by having a visual color code to the two logs. Even custom font colors would be acceptable, but the font color setting overrides all panes at once.

[image: Example]

Comment: Thought, you need to make feature request to the author. Or you may try another terminal.